# Simple web service for sending email notifications?

Tags: php, web-services, email, notifications, monitoring

My hobby PHP site sends me an email when a problem occurs or a user sends me a message via a web form. This usually works well, but sometimes my hosting provider does not send emails reliably, so some emails get lost and I'm not notified about problems or messages.

As an alternative I used Notifo for notifications which was simple to use and reliable, but unfortunately they kicked the bucket.

Looking for other solutions I found [Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) which should be pretty reliable and it's apparently completely free for small users (1000 emails/month is more than enough for my small site), but it can do much more than I need, so I'm looking for a simpler service first.

Do you about a simple web service which can send me a mail when I call it via HTTP and has a free tier for small users?

Comment: belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, I wanted to ask it there, but I followed some other question first and did not notice I came over to SO. If a mod can migrate it to there then I'm not against it.

Comment: Why closing the question instead of migrating it to webapps or webmasters? It would have been a more constructive solution.

Comment: None of us voting for closing have the ability to migrate unfortunately. You could flag it for mod attention I guess...

Comment: Then it would have been more constructive for you to flag it for mod attention in the first place, instead of voting for closing. Especially because it was you in the first comment who said it belonged to webapps.

Comment: That's what voting for closing is supposed to do in the first place. For some popular sites migration is automatic. webapps is not one of them, so the question needs to be reviewed manually.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few email services with a free option, other than Amazon:

- [PostageApp](http://www.postageapp.com/)
- [SendGrid](http://www.sendgrid.com/)
- [Mailjet](http://www.mailjet.com/)

(**FULL DISCLOSURE:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp. Happy to answer questions about emails for your side project though!)

Comment: [AlphaMail](http://comfirm.se) is another service that also have a free option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a free teir, but [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) (the predecessor to SNS) is very reliable and is used just for simple emails, no frills.

It can be integrated via an HTTP API, and just recently they added SMTP integration.  I use it for several projects, and I'm really satisfied with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. $0.10 per a thousand emails doesn't look too pricey.

Comment: Yeah, it's really affordable.  Well worth the $0.10 a month to not worry about message deliverability ever again for your project ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could sign up for a free Sendgrid account. The free account gives you 200 e-mails per day, I believe, which sounds like more than you'd need.

Comment: Thanks. 200 emails per day is enough. I usually get a few dozen a day.